# What 'language' is this written in? (from 1994) - Is it Fortran?

Tags: fortran, signal-processing

I'm trying to replicate something like this in Matlab and I don't understand how it's written. I'm just trying to check some documentation, but idk what to search.

For example, I'm guessing the line: "If (L.LE.M)  Then" --> means if L is **l**ess than or **e**qual to M, then.., but I can't be certain about anything.

**Part 1:**
[image: part 1]

**Part 2:**
[image: part 2 - better to look at]

Comment: Sure looks like Fortran to me.

Comment: It's some dialect of Fortran

Comment: And `.LE.` does indeed mean "less than or equal", see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fortran/Fortran_control

Comment: By the way, you didn't say, but this code appears to come from the paper "Using the Matrix Pencil Method to Estimate the Parameters of a Sum of Complex Exponentials" by Tapan K. Sarkar and Odilon Pereira, *IEEE Antennas and Propagation Magazine*, Vol. 37 No. 1, February 1995, pp 48-55, https://doi.org/10.1109/74.370583.  Please always cite the source when including code or other material that is not your own; failure to do so can be considered plagiarism.

Comment: It shares pretty much all the features mentiioned in the answer in the link. Iincluding the non-standard ones. It is Fortran 90 (implicit none, end do, end if) with features that are not standard Fortran at all (real*8, complex*16), in fixed source form (comments, line continuations).